# can we assign a integer value to a reference variable?

Tags: c++

It is not possible to assign an integer value to a reference variable directly, say like:

```
int &x=10; //not possible
```

Is there any other way we can modify this statement to make it possible?

But not like this:

```
int a=10;int &x=a;
```

This works fine. But I want some other way or modify a little bit my expression and make it work!

Comment: Why do you need this ? It would work like a normal variable from then on :-/ so.. why don't you use a normal variable ?

Comment: @ascanio: Since when does C have a concept of references?

Comment: I didn't know the concept of reference variable

Comment: @ascanio: C does also not have a syntax like `int &x=10;`.

Comment: @phresnel: in fact, that produced the compile error..

Comment: @ascanio: But because of the rvalue, to which you can't bind a reference ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because 10 is of the type "const int". You can turn that into a reference, but you can't make it non-const without violating some logic at the least.

```
const int &a = 10;
```

that'll work.

```
int &b = const_cast<int &>(static_cast<const int &>(10));
```

will also compile, but you can't modify b (as that would imply modifying the actual "10" value).

Comment: In the second example, I don't think it should compile, you can't convert an rvalue to non-const reference type even with `const_cast`. And if it did, you couldn't read `b` anyway, unless the lifetime of any temporary object that it was referring to was extended beyond the initialization. So for example, you can write `int &b = const_cast<int &>(static_cast<const int &>(10));`, but all that achieves is a dangling reference.

Comment: It's not a dangling reference as the value 10 is referenced and static. It'll be in read-only data though, so modifying it will result in a page fault. Also, it will compile. You can even do: const X &f = function(); with the function declared as "X function();". The lifetime of that temporary will then be until the end of the block in which the const-reference is held. I'm not saying it's clear or overtly logical (or even useful)...

Comment: Where does the standard say all this? AFAIK There is no requirement that integer literals be placed in read-only data, even when a const reference is taken to them. The implementation is perfectly entitled to stick 'em on the stack, then re-use the stack for something else later. The temporary's lifetime isn't inherently extended to the end of the block, it's extended to the lifetime of the reference to which it's bound, which in your `f` case is the block, but in my two-casts case is still only the statement.

Comment: Just checked GCC, and it doesn't put the value in read-only data, so no page fault. Of course it's still UB to modify the value. I haven't yet persuaded GCC to re-use that stack for something else, though, so in effect what GCC gives you from my two-casts code is a mutable `int` object whose lifetime is to the end of the block. But that's not guaranteed, it's just what GCC appears to do.

Comment: "Also, it will compile." - not in GCC, not in Comeau, not according to the C++03 standard (none of the rules in 5.2.11 allows an rvalue to be converted to a reference type by `const_cast`). YMMV.

Comment: From n3242, 2.14.2 [lex.icon] "2. The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 6 in which its value can be represented." None of the types listed in Table is `const` qualified. An integer literal is a prvalue of type e.g. `int`, never `const int`. (What Steve said is also extremely relevant to how wrong that code is.)

Comment: This is not at all true. `10` is of type `int`, the fact that you can't assign to non-const reference is because it's an rvalue, nothing to do with constness.

Comment: You're all right; I didn't double-check it with the standard or a compiler. You have to manually convert it to a const reference before removing the constness.

Answer (score 6):

The reference as the name says has to reference to something. How do you want to assign a value to it if it doesn't reference anything?

Answer (score 4):

The crux is that `10` is a constant – somewhat obviously: you cannot change its value. But if you try to assign it to an `int` reference, this would mean that the value were modifiable: an `int&` is a *modifiable* value.

To make your statement work, you can use a `const` reference:

```
int const& x = 10;
```

But as “cnicutar” has mentioned in a comment, this is pretty useless; just assign the `10` to a plain `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a reference-to-nonconst to anything immutable.

- The standard permits storing compile time constants in ROM (btw, attempting to modify `const_cast<>`ed compile time constants yields undefined behaviour)
- This would basically strip of the `const`, even if the `const` is invisible, therefore subverting the whole const-correctness-thing

However, you can bind a reference-to-const to nearly everything, including temporaries:

- [GotW: A candidate for the most important const](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

Consider this a "feature".

Answer (score 2):

References refer to *objects* (perhaps temporary objects), not to *values*. If you want to store a value somewhere, assign it to an object, not to a reference.

As a special case, `const int &a = 10;` initializes the reference `a` to refer to a temporary object with the value 10, *and* it extends the lifetime of that temporary to the end of the scope of `a` (12.2/5). That's pretty useless with an integer literal, but occasionally useful with objects of class type. Still, this does *not* assign an integer value to a reference. It creates a temporary, and binds a reference to the temporary.

Answer (score 1):

in the C++0x, you can use int&& (rvalue references ), but this can be used as function parameter.

Comment: Not only as a function parameter, e.g. a variable at block scope is possible.